# Modify ToolTip Text inside ListElement (QML)

Tags: qt, qml, tooltip, qtquick2

I'm actually developing a software with Python and QML. I've manage to learn it by myself and thanks to some good videos but I've come across a problem lately that I can't manage to deal with.

So here is my ListView Element :

```
ListView {
    id: listView
    anchors.fill:parent
    anchors.bottom: start_button.top
    anchors.rightMargin: 10
    anchors.leftMargin: 10
    anchors.topMargin: 20

    delegate: informationDelegate
    model: ListModel { id:informationModel }
}
```

Well, as you can see I have a delegate to "pre-format" my list :

```
Component{
    id:informationDelegate

    Column {
        spacing: 5
        height: 60

        Text { text: name ; font.bold: true ; color: "#ffffff" }
        Text { text: path ; color: "#ffffff" ; ToolTip.delay: 1000 ; ToolTip.visible: ma.containsMouse ; ToolTip.text: qsTr("Tooltip empty")
            MouseArea { id: ma ; anchors.fill: parent ; hoverEnabled: true}
        }
    }
}
```

And then, I'd like to modify the Tooltip.text value in a JS function but I can't find a way to do it. I've tried many things but don't really find a way to do it.

```
informationModel.clear()
informationModel.append ({"name" : "Ansible Playbook :" , "path.ToolTip.text" : obj.ansiblePath , "path" : obj.ansiblePath.split('/').pop() })
informationModel.append ({"name" : "Configuration File :" , "path.ToolTip.text" : qsTr(obj.ansiblePath) , "path" : displayConf.split('/').pop() })
informationModel.append ({"name" : "Firmware File :" , "path.ToolTip.text" : qsTr(obj.ansiblePath) , "path" : displayFirmware.split('/').pop() })
```

Let me know if you have a hint about this issue ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong, the model does not directly modify the view but the view uses the model to modify itself, so in your case you must create a property and make a binding with the `ToolTip.text`:

```
Component{
    id:informationDelegate
    Column{
        required property string name
        required property string path
        required property string message

        spacing: 5
        height: 60

        Text {
            text: name
            font.bold: true
            color: "#ffffff"
        }
        Text {
            text: path
            ToolTip.delay: 1000
            ToolTip.visible: ma.containsMouse
            ToolTip.text: message
            MouseArea {
                id: ma
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
informationModel.clear()
informationModel.append({"name" : "Ansible Playbook :" , "message" :"message1" , "path" : "path1" })
informationModel.append({"name" : "Configuration File :" , "message" : "message2" , "path" : "path2"  })
informationModel.append({"name" : "Firmware File :" , "message" : "message3" , "path" : "path3"  })
```

Comment: Hi eyllanesc, you were really right here. I misunderstood how it worked but now I understand !
Again, a big thanks to you !

Comment: Hi @a-maxime. Please mark this post as the correct answer, so that we know that it solves the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Mark, it's already have been done 11 hours ago. I hope you can see it even if I'm a new user here. Have a great day !